# Implicit Solution to ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have come across an ODE of the form
$y'(x)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{y(x)}-y(x)^2\right)$
with condition $y(0)=K.$

The given implicit solution is

$y=4\left[\ln{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{y} +y}\left(1-\sqrt{K}\right)}{(1-\sqrt{y})\sqrt{1+\sqrt{K}+K}}\right)} +\sqrt{3}\arctan\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}\left(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{K}\right)}{3+(1+2\sqrt{K})(1+2\sqrt{y})}\right) 
\right]$

This could definitely be via Mathematica/Maple etc. I want to know how this implicit solution (or an equivalent to it) is computed?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $x = \ldots$?

Comment: Exactly. @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential equation $y' = f(y)$ is separable.  Write it as
$ \dfrac{dy}{f(y)} = dx$ and integrate to get
$x = \int \dfrac{dy}{f(y)} + C$.  In this case Maple gives an antiderivative of $1/f(y)$ as
$$ \ln  \left( {\frac { \left( -{y}^{2}-y-1 \right)  \left( y+\sqrt {y}+1
 \right)  \left( \sqrt {y}+1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( y-1 \right) ^{2}
 \left( \sqrt {y}-1 \right) ^{2} \left( -y+\sqrt {y}-1 \right) }}
 \right) -2\,\sqrt {3}\arctan \left( {\frac {\sqrt {3} \left( 2\,{y}^{
2}-y+3\,\sqrt {y}-1 \right) }{-6\,{y}^{3/2}-3\,\sqrt {y}+3\,y-3}}
 \right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

For me, it would easier to solve
$$\frac 1 {x'(y)}=\frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{y}-y^2\right)$$ which would give
$$x=c_1+2 \log \left(\frac{y+\sqrt{y}+1}{\left(1-\sqrt{y}\right)^2 }\right)+4 \sqrt{3} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{y}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$